# Play a sound upon collecting coin in Swift SKAction

Tags: swift, avaudiosession

I have a code in Swift which plays a bird game. A bird collects eggs. I want to play a coin sound upon bird touching the egg. I tried code below but it's not playing upon contact. How can I accomplish it?

```
do {
            // Preperation
            try     AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch _ {
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
        }

        // Play the sound
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL:     alertSound)
        } catch _{
        }

       audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
```

Comment: And the C tag just sneaked in, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a path to the sound file

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("(sound name)", ofType: (type) )!
```

Url for the path

```
var url = NSURL()
```

Variable to hold sound

```
var soundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
```

Then when you want to play the sound

```
url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
do {
    let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
    soundEffect = sound
    sound.play()
} catch {

}
```

Comment: Hi Kobi ,how are you? I tried your suggestion.When i build and run it it gives just one warning(Variable 'soundEffect' was written to, but never read)  but it doesn't play any sound.I have good .wav file that works.Is there anything else i have to add to the code? Thanks

Comment: Should work just the way it is, make sure the sound name is correct and it should be fine.